# passing xml variable through soapclient

Tags: php, xml, soap

i am using `PHP` and `soapclient`. one of the web services send `XML` data through a variable. (a string variable contain `XML`). in `PHP` when i print or echo it, the tags not shown. just values printed. something like this: `

> `value1value2value3value4...`

how i can access to the variable `XML` data,i want pure `XML` code. thanks for any reply.

in web service
variable=`

```
<modul>
<name>value1</name>
</modul>
<modul>
<name>value2</name>
</modul>`
```

my result after print variable:

> value1value2

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to generate a WSDL(web service description language). WSDL is an XML format for describing network services as a set of endpoints operating on messages containing either document-oriented or procedure-oriented information.

You can use php nusoap library to generate the WSDL

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

Any client application generate client stub from WSDL.

For the testing purpose you can use soapUI

http://www.soapui.org/

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in the source of the web page? Maybe browser is not recognizing tags and just not displaying them? If this is the case then you just need to use DOMDocument::load*() or SimpleXML to parse string as xml.